# foreach with colors leads to "undefined control sequence"

Tags: pgfplots, errors, foreach, pgffor

The following MWE works nicely when I remove the optional argument `[\forcol]` from the `\addplot`command or when I change it to `red`, for example. Though I would like the curves to have different colors as defined in my list `{1/black,2/red,3/green,4/blue,5/orange}`, so I tried it as the following, but then it throws me the error

> "! Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \foreach \foridx/\forcol in {1/black,2/red,3/green,4/blue,5/orange}{
            \addplot[\forcol]{x^\foridx};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What is my mistake? I would like to have this feature to set up a command for plotting many data files.

Comment: referencing section 8 of the manual, you can use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \foridx/\forcol in {1/black,2/red,3/green,4/blue,5/orange}{
            \addplot[\forcol]{x^\foridx};
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[\forcol]{x^\foridx};}
            \temp
      }`

Comment: @cmhughes: great, this works, thanks! You can create an answer of this!
But I don't really understand this "magic" (even with the description of the manual), what the "extra groups" are that are not introduced here.

Comment: @cmhughes: I just realize you had the ` \addplot[\forcol]{x^\foridx};` also outside your `temp` environment. This should be omitted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try some `\expandafter...` statements to expand the `\foreach` loops. `\foreach` loops can be quite tricky, in my point of view, due to the way the `\forcol` macros are defined by `pgffor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
     \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \foridx/\forcol in {1/black,2/red,3/green,4/blue,5/orange}{
            \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\forcol]{x^\foridx};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i simply removed  `[\forcol]` and the plot showed. but it has a lot of points in it.

Comment: @Naphaneal: of course this works, but I would like my colors to be used.

Comment: @Naphaneal: Well, what's the issue then?

Comment: Christian: thanks for this solution. Seems clearer than the [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301226/foreach-with-colors-leads-to-undefined-control-sequence?noredirect=1#comment729830_301226) of @cmhughes

Comment: @riddleculous: Well, that might be the solution for more complicated setups, though

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: just out of curiosity: if I understand this correctly, the `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` combined with the cmhughes `temp` definition is essentially the same but the temporary definition can't be used with the standard `\foreach`. What would be an example where I can't use your approach? Or will it just get too cluttered when multiple `\expandafter`s would be needed?

Comment: @riddleculous: The version by cmhughes (in his comment above) is using an ungrouped `foreach` loop and an pre-expansion of `\forcol`, with `\edef` (\expanded \def), which is effectively the same)

Comment: @riddleculous: It can be really complicated with `\expandafter`s, in my point of view, in nested `\foreach` loops and multiple `\addplot[\foo,\forbar,\morefoo]{...}`

Comment: Your and cmhughes code are not the same. You are both expanding the color command (which is needed), but cmhughes also avoid the grouping around the \addplots. I would suggest to use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` in your code too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: why is the grouping bad?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I've replaced `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` instead of the usual `\foreach`

Comment: @riddleculous: The axis environment defers a lot work to the end (e.g. the generation of the legend), and the addplots are not independant (see e.g. the cycle list, labels, maximum etc), so I would avoid to separate them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: in general, that makes sense, so I better use the ungrouped solution right from the beginning Thanks!