# \pgfforeachungrouped with three arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, pgffor

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301226/78282) of mine, with a slight addition. I would like to loop over data in a file and give the plot styles as a list. In the old question I gave only a color and an index and Christian Hupfer came up with a working [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301228/78282) as did, [with a slight variation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301226/foreach-with-colors-leads-to-undefined-control-sequence#comment729830_301226), cmhughes.

Now, I would like to specify the style more precisely. For example, I would like to be able to draw dotted or dashed lines like in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
     \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \foridx/\forcol/\forstyle in {1/black/solid,2/red/dashed,3/green/dotted,4/blue/solid,5/orange/dotted}{
            \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\forcol,\forstyle]{x^\foridx};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I leave out `\forstyle` and the third arguments in the list, I get Christian Hupfer's solution which is working. Like this, it produces many errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...pgfplots@foreach@loc@TMPb \forstyle 

l.9       }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 3 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no / in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyscurrentkey ->\forstyle 

l.9       }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

NOTE: coordinate (2Y5.0e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (
in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y4.5833334e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y4.1666669e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y3.7500003e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y3.3333337e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y2.9166672e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y2.5000006e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y2.083334e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unboun
ded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y1.6666675e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y1.2500009e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y8.333344e-1],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y4.166677e-1],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (2Y9.9e-7],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded 
(in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y4.1666573e-1],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbo
unded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y8.3333243e-1],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbo
unded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y1.24999913e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbo
unded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y1.6666656e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y2.0833322e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y2.4999988e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y2.9166653e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y3.3333319e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y3.7499985e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y4.166665e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unboun
ded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y4.5833316e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x^').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9       }

(That was another \errmessage.)

NOTE: coordinate (1Y4.9999982e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbou
nded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump).
```

With the linked code snippet from cmhughes, I couldn't get it to work either with similar errors (probably the same problem)

So I tried to give the arguments to `\addplot` in a list:

```
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \foridx/\forstyle in {1/{black,solid},2/{red,dashed},3/{green,dotted},4/{blue,solid},5/{orange,dotted}}{
   \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\forstyle]{x^\foridx};
   }
```

This compiles but it produces only a solid black line (it loops only over the first element)

In fact, I could not get any example with three variables working. How do I use `pgffor` with three or more variables?

Answer (score 4):

In [PGFPlotsToDo list (v1.14) on page 35](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstodo.pdf#page=35) it is written:

> `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` cannot be combined with three or more
>   arguments like `\foreach`

So one has to find another solution to the problem at present. But luckily this
is easily possible in this case by defining a custom `cycle list`.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % create a cycle list that fits your needs ...
    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{
       {black,solid},
       {red,dashed},
       {green,dotted},
       {blue,solid},
       {orange,dotted}%
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=-100,
            ymax=100,
            legend pos=south east,
            % ... and apply it here ...
            % (or in `\pgfplotsset' if it should be used as default for all plots)
            cycle list name=mylist,
        ]
            % ... then your loop simplifies to ...
            \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
                % ... where I just added `very thick' so the result can be
                % seen easier
                \addplot+ [very thick] {(x)^\i};
                    \addlegendentryexpanded{$x^\i$};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]